# Is it possible to show a loading gif / image BEFORE the page starts loading

Tags: javascript

The current solution i have implemented is also the most popular one online.
Add a div above the actual page, and either make this div (or the image inside it) width & height 100% or make the div with actual content have `display:none` at first.

There is one issue with this.. it takes a while before the loading gif is loaded.. 
I want this to be the FIRST thing shown and loaded, before any other loading happens..

As you can also see in the live demo here; it takes a while before the loading image is loaded...

Demo: http://www.netavatar.co.in/demos/loading-image/loadingimage.html

http://www.netavatar.co.in/2011/05/31/how-to-show-a-loading-gif-image-while-a-page-loads-using-javascript-and-css/

Answer (score 0):

HTML loads elements in the order they appear in the markup, thus the solution you followed is the best you can use. There is always going to be a delay, as even the loading image requires time to load, which is what you are witnessing.

Comment: Yes, but on my actual page i have about 700 lines of javascript code above the page.. slowing the initial load of the loading image alot..

Comment: Why not load your JavaScript after the page has finished loading the main content by placing it at the end, or at least after the loading image? Just load the specific lines of code you need to display your loading screen before the loading image.

Comment: That's interesting, will try this out, never crossed my mind lol.